# How to Format Text in Eclipse with cfeclipse plug-in

Tags: eclipse, coldfusion, coldfusionbuilder, cfeclipse

How can I reformat the Text(.cfm file) ?

I am trying to do CTRL+SHIFT+F which works for java files, But its not working with Coldfusion files.
?
Is there anyway I can format the text?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

not implemented in CFEclipse nor CF Builder (YET)

Comment: Oh.. Then it is Manual work to format for Coldfusion code?  :(

Comment: yup~ stick to the coding convention, or beg Adobe to add that to ColdFusion builder. :)

Answer (score 0):

With the release of Coldfusion Builder 2 they have added support for formatting code.  Press Ctrl+Shift+F Windows or Command+Shift+F Mac to format existing code in a Coldfusion Builder 2 IDE.